# If $n\times n$ matrix A is symmetric, is $A^{10}$ symmetric also?

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetry

If $n\times n$ matrix A is symmetric, is $A^{10}$ symmetric also? All I can deduce is that $A^{T}=A$, but that doesn't give me much in trying to show that $A^{10}$ is symmetric. Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: *Hint:* $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$. Now use induction.

Comment: So that means that $(A^{2})^{T}$=$2A^{T}$, right? Then as $A^{T}$ is symmetric, $(A^{2})^{T}$ is symmetric also?

Comment: How did you get $2A^T$, @ElectronicGeek

Comment: $(A^2)^T = (AA)^T$, right? Now use the above with $B = A$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well, $(AA)^{T}=A^{T}A^{T}=2A^{T}$, right?

Comment: No, $CC\neq 2C$ (in general.) @ElectronicGeek

Comment: @ElectronicGeek No. $A^T A^T = (A^T)^2$, and $A$ is symmetric, hence $A^T = A$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh, I see, duh.

Comment: The point is not the matrices, the point is, that $2C = C+C \ne CC = C \cdot C = C^2$ (in general).

Comment: Oh wait. So that means $A^{2}=(A^{2})^T$, right? That means $A^{2}$ is symmetric... Oh ok, thanks. Figured it out myself lol